# How can I connect an already existing/compiled .dll to a new project in Visual Studio?

Tags: visual-c++, dllimport, precompiled

I have a previously compiled dll file. I've lost the source code unfortunately.
But I know the functions, header names and namespaces on it.

Is it possible to add this dll to a new project in VS? If so what code should I use? (not sure how to use dllimport in this case)

*Both the DLL and the new project are on C++ .net 2.0. I'm using VS2008*

Comment: You'll need to make a lib file (search the web for how to do that) or use LoadLibrary / GetProcAddress.

Comment: Depends, is it a managed or native dll?

Comment: They have managed headers and component classes

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should just have to add a reference to your project that points to the dll.
Right click the project-> go down to add -> reference. Or Expand the Project and right click the references node and click add.
[image]

This opens a dialog with 4 items to the left. click on browse then click the browse button at the bottom. Find your dll and click add and then Ok to close the dialog.
[image]
After that use it as you would any other dll.

Comment: Thanks but I need to know how to do it in VS2008. The interface looks quite different.

Comment: This is 2013 with the dark theme applied but I've used 2005 all way to 2013 and the steps have not changed much if at all.

Comment: thanks. i managed to get it working in 2008 as well. I forgot to mark this as an answer. I'll do it now.